# How to find AWS Lambda nameservers using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I am using a Lambda function to connect to a service in my VPC and it needs to resolve an internal address, therefore I need to allow connections from Lambda to hit the my internal nameservers, but don't want to allow UDP to 0.0.0.0/0 on port 53.

How can I find out the IP addresses of the nameservers Lambda will use so I can put them into my security groups rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your VPC, the DNS server will be the the base of the VPC network range plus two. For example if your VPC CIDR block is 10.0.0.0/24 then the Amazon will reserve 10.0.0.2 for the DNS server. This is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html).

You could also just allow outbound connections to your VPC CIDR block instead of having to open up 0.0.0.0/0. Although you should note that a Lambda function inside a VPC does not have a public IP address, so it can't access anything outside of the VPC without going through a NAT gateway anyway.

---

To calculate this in Terraform, let's assume you have a reference to the VPC somehow, like so:

```
data "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  id = "${var.vpc_id}"
}
```

Then you can use Terraform's `cidrhost()` function to find the IP address, like this:

```
locals {
  dns_server = cidrhost(data.aws_vpc.my_vpc.cidr_block, 2)
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_dns" {
  type            = "outbound"
  from_port       = 53
  to_port         = 53
  protocol        = "udp"
  cidr_blocks     = "${local.dns_server}/32"

  security_group_id = "sg-123456"
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I also saw this in the link you posted `You cannot filter traffic to or from a DNS server using network ACLs or security groups` so maybe this isn't necessary, will try again